# Is this a breach of the consistency principle in causal inference?

Tags: bayesian, causality, treatment-effect, observational-study

My understanding of the consistency principle is that the observed outcome is equal to the potential outcome. i.e. let T = treatment, if T=1 then then the Observed outcome (Y) is equal to the potential outcome i.e. Y(1) = Y . This implies that there can't be 'multiple versions of the same treatment' which will lead to differnt outcome.

I'm struggling to understand this concept. E.G. i want to find out if owning a cat increases happiness. In my data i see that the type of a cat can vary. If i observe that owning a britsih blue hair increases happiness in my sample data but than owning a maincoon cat decreases happiness does this mean a **violation**? What if i also see that a maincoon cat increases happiness in some subjects too?
e.g. my data looks like:

```
treatment  | type cat | outcome 
1          | British  | increase
1          | Maincoon | increase 
1          | Maincoon | decrease
```

E.G. if i had the above data, would i be able to run any causal inference experiments?

If i include the 'type of cat' into my structural causal model, would consistency naturally follow? How could i embed this variable 'type of cat' into an SCM?

*please let me know if i am understanding this correctly!*

e.g.

[image]

source: https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/JDWTro62tRAHzvhEH/causal-inference-sequence-part-1-basic-terminology-and-the

Comment: The principle does not rule out different treatments. Maybe an easier example than cats is doses of a drug, which can vary (as can the type of cat). But if a person gets the same cat, it gets the same outcome. Also, the principle does not rule out heterogenous treatment effects. That is, the same cat may affect different people differently (including with different signs).

Comment: I was confused due to the above reference